# How to parse string to date format in java

Tags: java, date

I have a file file_20201013_012417.txt and I want to validate the timestamp 20201013_012417 format of this file is YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS.

I have tried SimpleDateFormat , but getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date execption.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, you can try to edit the concurrency number for your pipeline at the last step of creating.

Please see the figure below.
[image]